# How do I compute the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 - e^{x/n})^n$?

Tags: calculus

I can write $e^{x/n} = 1 + \frac{x}{n} + o((x/n)^2)$, so that $(1 - e^{x/n})^n = (x/n + o((x/n)^2))^n \approx (x/n)^n$. Is this correct? Where do I go from here?

Comment: $|\frac x n| <\frac 1 2$ evntually and $(\frac 1 2 )^{n} \to 0$

Comment: Take logarithms and compose Taylor series for large values of $n$

Comment: That would be $O((x/n)^2)$, not $o$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $n \to \infty$,
from the taylor series expansion you would get,
$$(1 - e^{\frac{x}{n}})^n \approx (\frac{-x}{n})^n$$
Here, $\frac{-x}{n} \approx 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

And $0^n = 0$,  since for a number $|m| < 1$ and exponent $k$, $|m^k| < |m|$ if $k > 1$. (For example, $0.5^2$ = 0.25 which is less than 0.5)

So, the answer is $0$.